# access content of TabHost TabWidget

Tags: android, xamarin.android

i have a TabHost and my tab widgets content are activity(contain EditTexts etc) and a save button on top of tab host.

**locations:**

-TabHost in one activity(tab activity)

-Save button is child of TabHost activity

-each TabWidget in an activity

i want when user click save button,grab all edit text,spinner etc value in tabwidgets and save them in database

it's about 3 day i am searching and testing!

### **Edit**

code:

```
        #region tabs

        TabHost.TabSpec spec;     // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent;            // Reusable Intent for each tab

        //--------------------------------
        intent = new Intent(this, typeof(FrmMelkPersonalInfoTabActivity));
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        spec = TabHost.NewTabSpec("FrmMelkPersonalInfoTabActivity");

        spec.SetIndicator("مشخصات شخص", Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.tab1));
        View tab = LayoutInflater.From(TabHost.Context).Inflate(Resource.Id.ta, null);

        spec.SetContent(intent);
        TabHost.AddTab(spec);

        //--------------------------------
        intent = new Intent(this, typeof(FrmMelkAbaadZaminInfoTabActivity));
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

        spec = TabHost.NewTabSpec("FrmMelkAbaadZaminInfoTabActivity");
        spec.SetIndicator("ابعاد", Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.tab2));
        spec.SetContent(intent);
        TabHost.AddTab(spec);

        TabHost.CurrentTab = 0;

        Button btnSave = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnSave);
        btnSave.Click += new EventHandler(btnSave_Click);

    void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinearLayout llMain = (LinearLayout)TabHost.GetChildAt(0);
        FrameLayout flTabContents = (FrameLayout)llMain.GetChildAt(2);

        var tab1 = flTabContents.GetChildAt(0);
        string father = tab1.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtFather_Name).Text;

    }
```

by @K. Oulebsir help,i use GetChildAt method and could access my content,but in testing,i found that tab indexs for GetChildAt(index) is not sortable,this mean that when i am in tab1,i can access tab1 elements,but i can access tab2 elements only when i navigated to tab2 after tab1,Other means ,order of my tabs navigate,make tab indexs

maybe i can access tab elements only when those are showed before.

how i can access tab contents without need to loading or how i load them for accesibility without navigating to them?

someone sayed me i can do this only with fragments,i dont know

---

can everyone help me?
tanks

Answer (score 2):

You can access views in activities like this example:

```
public class Act1_Principale extends TabActivity implements OnTabChangeListener {
    private TabHost tabHost;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.lay_principale);
        tabHost = getTabHost();

        tabHost.addTab(createTab(Act1.class, title, drawable));
        tabHost.addTab(createTab(Act2.class, title, drawable));
        tabHost.addTab(createTab(Act3.class, title, drawable));
        tabHost.addTab(createTab(Act4.class, title, drawable));

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tabHost.getTabContentView().getChildAt(0).
                findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
            }
        });
    }

    private TabSpec createTab(final Class<?> intentClass, final String tag, final int drawable) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, intentClass);
        final View tab = LayoutInflater.from(getTabHost().getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tab, null);

        ((ImageView) tab.findViewById(R.id.tab_icon)).setImageResource(drawable);
        return getTabHost().newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tab).setContent(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: i am using Mono for android(.net),but api is same,i created my tabs by making intent from activity and you inflate tabs,i wanted to inflate tabs like you,but what is R.layout.tab? please read my Edit text,at my main post.